# First derivative of multivariate normal density with exchangeable correlation structure

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, multivariate-normal-distribution, derivative, scoring-rules

As part of a proof, I need to take the first derivative of the log of the following multivariate normal density: $(2\pi)^{-k/2} |\Sigma|^{-1/2} \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2} x'\Sigma^{-1}x\right)$.

In this case, the mean is zero and $\Sigma$ has an exchangeable correlation structure, thus $\Sigma = D A(\rho)D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $d = (\sigma_1, \ldots , \sigma_k)$ and $A(\rho) = (1-\rho)I + \rho jj^\top$, where $I$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix and $j = (1,\ldots,1)^\top$ is a vector of $1$s (of length $k$). I need to take derivatives with respect to $\sigma_j^2$, where $j \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$.

Clearly, the first algebraic steps are:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_j^2} \log \left[(2\pi)^{-k/2} |\Sigma|^{-1/2} \exp\left( \frac{-1}{2} x^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} x \right) \right]$$

$$= \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_j^2} \left[ \frac{-1}{2} \log |\Sigma| - \frac{-1}{2} x^\top \Sigma^{-1} x \right],$$

but I am getting stuck at the point where the derivative actually needs to be taken. How can I take the derivative with respect to $\sigma_j^2$?

I would appreciate any help on this! Eventually working towards showing that the first derivative (with respect to $\sigma^2$) is bounded, but for now, just need to derive a proper expression for the first derivative.

Comment: Although it might look daunting, in this case it's actually easy to express both $\log|\Sigma|$ and $\Sigma^{-1}$ explicitly in terms of the $\sigma_j.$  The problem reduces to a *univariate* calculation, so try it with $k=1$ variable first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 & \cdots & \sigma_k\end{bmatrix}'$ by $d$, $\operatorname{diag}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ by $X$. Since $|\Sigma| = |D|^2|A(\rho)| = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^k\sigma_i^2|A(\rho)|$ and $x'D = d'X$, the log-likelihood function is
\begin{align} l(\sigma_1^2, \ldots, \sigma_k^2) &= -\frac{1}{2}\log|\Sigma| - \frac{1}{2}x'DA(\rho)^{-1}Dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^k\log\sigma_i^2 - \frac{1}{2}d'XA(\rho)^{-1}Xd + \text{constant}. 
\end{align}
It thus follows by the quadratic form differentiation formula $\partial z'Mz/\partial z = 2Mz$ and the chain rule that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial l(\sigma_1^2, \ldots, \sigma_k^2)}{\partial \sigma_j^2}
&= -\frac{1}{2\sigma_j^2} - \frac{1}{\sigma_j}e_j'XA(\rho)^{-1}Xd \\
&= -\frac{1}{2\sigma_j^2} - \frac{1}{\sigma_j}
\begin{bmatrix}0 & \cdots & x_j & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}
A(\rho)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} x_1\sigma_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_k\sigma_k
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $e_j$ is the $k$-long column vector with all entries $0$ but the $j$-th entry $1$.

As $A(\rho) = (1 - \rho)I + \rho jj'$, the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) gives
\begin{align}
A(\rho)^{-1} &= (1 - \rho)^{-1}I - (1 - \rho)^{-2}\frac{\rho jj'}{1 + (1 - \rho)^{-1}\rho k} \\
&= (1 - \rho)^{-1}\left[I - \frac{\rho jj'}{1 + (k - 1)\rho}\right]. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial l(\sigma_1^2, \ldots, \sigma_k^2)}{\partial \sigma_j^2}
= -\frac{1}{2\sigma_j^2} - \frac{x_j^2}{1 - \rho} +
\frac{x_j\rho}{(1 - \rho)\sigma_j}\frac{\sum_i x_i\rho_i}{1 + (k - 1)\rho}.
\end{align}

Comment: this is really helpful, thank you! I think you forgot the $\log$ when you go from $-\frac{1}{2} log \left| \Sigma \right|$ to $-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2$, right? I think it should be $-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^k \log(\sigma_i^2)$, whose derivative is $-\frac{1}{2\sigma_i^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, I believe the result of the Sherman-Morrison formula (inside the brackets $[]$)should have a $-$ instead of a $+$, correct?

Comment: Yes, I will edit later.

Answer (score 3):

Not a full solution, but a few hints to help you on your way:

$$\log|\Sigma| =2\log|D|+\log|A|$$

$$\Sigma^{-1}=D^{-1}A^{-1}D^{-1}$$

$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{1-\rho}\left(I-\frac{\rho}{1+(k-1)\rho}jj^\top\right)$$

$$x^\top D^{-1} j j^\top D^{-1} x = \left(j^\top D^{-1} x\right)^2 =\left( \sum_a \sigma_a^{-1}x_a\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks! I working with this and it is helpful. Could you point me to a source providing these identities, or something that can be cited? (especially the inverse formula)

Comment: Any basic linear algebra book will state and prove three of these.  The fourth, about $A^{-1},$ can be derived in many ways and follows from various considerations (consider the eigenspaces and eigenvalues of $A,$ for instance, which can be found by inspection) -- but the acid test of any matrix inversion formula is to multiply the putative inverse $A^{-1}$ by the original matrix $A$ and check that the identity matrix results.  That doesn't even require a citation, really. If you want one, check out the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sherman+morrison).

Comment: Thanks @whuber!